# isdone.dll problem, running Elder Scrolls V on WINE , how to fix it with Wine?

Tags: wine, games, winetricks

I got a problem running some game installers on wine , and I get an error about `ISDONE.DLL`

This DLL file is not found in Winetricks.

Installing The Elder Scrolls V : Skyrim, this is the error I get:

Comment: Probably Winehq group would be able to help you. Also add additional info on what game it is, what error is displayed, to help us assist you.

Comment: I'll edit my question , add information. Edit: Added.

Comment: Fixed With Upgrading Wine to Latest Version 1.4 now.

Comment: @MahdiDibaie that would be a good answer - could you do this please and accept your own answer by clicking the tick button next to your answer.  Many thanks.

Comment: Sure, Answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading my Wine to 1.4 (latest as of May 2012) the issue is resolved!

Now installer runs without any errors about ISDONE.dll.